# using BeforeTransaction or AfterTransaction annotation instead of NotTransactional

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, transactions

in javaDoc was writing that `@NotTransactional` is deprecated.

Author of javaDoc offers use `@BeforeTransaction` or `@AfterTransaction`

```
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class CandidateServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest {

    @Test
    @NotTransactional
    public void method1() {
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() {
    }

    @Test
    public void method3() {
    }

}


@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
public class AbstractServiceTest  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests{
 ...
}
```

how can I do it in the above code ?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of those 2 annotations? They're not meant for test methods, but for methods that must run before/after each transactional test method. For non transactional test methods, the doc says: *in favor of moving the non-transactional test method to a separate (non-transactional) test class*

Comment: before/after each(caution) transactional test method

Comment: why @NotTransactional is deprecated ?

Comment: what is bad at this annotation ?

Comment: Because Spring considered it cleaner that way. Extending a class that is supposed to only have transactional test methods but marking some of them as non-transactional is not very clean, and unsimilar to how production transactional classes and methods work. It's much cleaner to use a non-transactional class, and mark the transactional methods with @Transactional, just as you would do with a Spring service.

Comment: I have understood your idea